# How to change the ower of the mounted directory in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to store my database data Permanently using docker-compose in WSL(Windows).
My docker-compose.yml file is below.
`/C/Users/XXX/Documents/dev/db-data` is the database data directory and this directory will store data permanently.
I could build the container using below docker-compose.yml.

```
db_docker:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    env_file:
        - .env.mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
        - /C/Users/XXX/Documents/dev/db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

But I couldn't access this container's database and the error message is like below.

> ERROR 29 (HY000): File './mysql/user.MYD' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

I searched this error message and I found the ownership of `/var/lib/mysql` is `root:root`.
    drwxrwxrwx 2 root  root  4096 Nov 27 03:42 mysql
    drwxrwx--- 2 mysql mysql 4096 Nov 16 01:14 mysql-files
    drwxr-x--- 2 mysql mysql 4096 Nov 16 01:14 mysql-keyring

I tested how the ownership will change if I remove the volumes setting from docker-compose.yml. And I built the container using below setting file.

```
db_docker:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    env_file:
        - .env.mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

In this conditions,  the ownership of `/var/lib/mysql` is `mysql:mysql` and I could access my database.

From these facts, mounting file will fix the ownership of `/var/lib/mysql` to `root:root` and I can solve my problem if I could change the permmision of `/var/lib/mysql`.

Next, I tried like below. `999` is the UID and GID of mysql, but permmision of `/var/lib/mysql` is `root:root`.

```
db_docker:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    env_file:
        - .env.mysql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    user: "999:999"
    volumes:
        - /C/Users/XXX/Documents/dev/db-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is my story of thinking and I couldn't solve this problem until now.
How can I change the ownership of the mounted directory?

Comment: Please provide security tab info of "/C/Users/XXX/Documents/dev/db-data" directory property.

Comment: @VirendraJadeja Hi. The result of `ls -l` is `drwxrwxrwx 1 Xxx Xxx 512`. `Xxx` is my windows local user name.

Comment: I was facing same issue. You need to alter security group for db-data diretory in Windows. You need to add user called Everyone and provide read and write permission and add it to security group.

Comment: @VirendraJadeja Hi. Thank you for your reply. Do I have to sign out current account and log in Everyone account? It's good. But If I have to sign out and log in when I use docker, it's little troublesome for me.
I think this problem is caused with windows file system and if I try to solve this problem I have to use complicated way like your way.
So I have to give up about thinking this problem and I'll research about docker system and windows filesystem more deeply.
I'm sorry that I couldn't adopt your way.

Comment: just store your db-data in different directory other than C drive. That might give enough permission for other users.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried your way, but I couldn't.
I tried like below.
    1. Created D drive.
    2. Added user called Everyone and provided read and write permission
    3. Run docker-compose

The ownerhip of `D:/db-data` is Xxx(Windows local user).

Comment: @VirendraJadeja I didn't add Everyone user to the security group and I couldn't understand. I searched this information but only the information for WindowsServer appeared and I thought it isn't relative for the security group you mean.